# How can the RecyclerView adapter talk back to parent layout?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I got a parent layout, `activity_main.xml`, with multiple views inside it, one of which is the `RecyclerView` view.

Within the recycler view, there are buttons that, once the user deals with them, I would like things to happen in the parent layout that is `activity_main.xml`.

For example, if I press a button on a `ViewHolder` item inside the child `RecyclerView`, in some cases, I would like changes to happen in the parent `activity_main.xml` layout.

However, my problem is that I don't know how to allow for this communication to happen.

What might be the best practices for such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an interface callback or use a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

This Stack Overflow answer is an example of an interface callback:
*[How to access component of MainActivity in recycler view to make onclick listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61733698/how-to-access-component-of-mainactivity-in-recycler-view-to-make-onclick-listene/61733999#61733999)*.

*[Kotlin Lambda Functions For RecyclerView Adapter Callbacks in Android](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kotlin-lambda-functions-for-recyclerview-adapter-callbacks-in-android/)* is for higher-order functions.

Comment: Thanks sir.  Perfecto .  Not sure I _entirely_ understood, but it inspired me to go into my `MainActivity` class, and defined methods to do things there.  Then, as I called `RecyclerView.Adapter`, I passed it `this` as an argument.  Then, inside `RecyclerView.Adapter`, I stored that as `val mainActivity: MainActivity` (Kotlin syntax).  Any Idea what did I just do?  Is it any of the methods above? .  It works fine now, but I'm worried if there are any long-term hazards that may unfold upon me and people that rely on me.